# Threads created in for loop does not work

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, for-loop, static

So I am currently experementing with Sockets and I want to have 3 ports open for client sockets to connect to. So this works if I manually add my threads.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => SyncServer.StartListening(new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1}), port));
t.Start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => SyncServer.StartListening(new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1}), port + 1));
t2.Start();
....
```

But I want to do it a bit cleaner so I tried with a for loop

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Threads>();
for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => SyncServer.StartListening(new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1}), port + i));
    t.Start();
    threads.Add(t);
}
```

The socket server does fully work but when I work with threads and add them manually. If I work with a for loop, the socket server with the port becomes unavailable. Probably because the thread is stopped and I fail to understand why.

Note: SyncServer is a static class and StartListening is a static method. If I use a for loop, they always get the latest portnumber (in this case 11003).

Comment: Related: [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is related to a classic "lambda function in a `for` loop" issue.

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Threads>();
for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
{
    // Copying the `i` value to another variable will help
    var innerI = i;
    Thread t = new Thread(() => SyncServer.StartListening(new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1}), port + innerI));
    t.Start();
    threads.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: What the hell, that indeed does the job. Thank you so much and I have never ever seen that before. I guess the i value gets overridden before the socket is fully setup. And innerI gets created each time on a new memory location.